# C# Visual Studio using resource files

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, resources

I'm trying to add two image files into the solution, so they will be compiled into the .exe, so I can load them right there instead of from an absolute path on the computer.

I believe I need to use resource files in Visual Studio, but I never have before. If I'm completely on the wrong track, please correct me.

Here's what I've done so far. In Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer, right click *Properties* → *Open* → *Resources* → *Add Resource* → *Add Existing File*...

So now I have both my images in the *Properties* → *Resources* tab. Now how do I get them back out in the C# code?

I'm using C#, [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) and [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010).

```
PictureBox pic;
pic.Image = new Bitmap( /* What is the address now? */ );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get them like `Properties.Resources.<name_of_your_resource>`

Comment: So, if you have added an image with name myLogo.jpg. You should be able to write Bitmap objBitmap = Properties.Resources.myLogo;

Comment: @Hps as far as I am concerned you have provided more information in this answer than all of MSDN does on resources.